# 404 error trying to load MEAN web app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express, crud

So I'm trying to set up a basic Todo list/CRUD application using the MEAN stack (Angular, MongoDB, Nodejs, Express) and I keep running into trouble when I switch around the routes and models in the directory and try to load up the application via node server on my command prompt.  When I move anything the error below is what I get via a command prompt error. Just an FYI, I'm a total NOOB.

```
App listening on port 3000
GET /api/todos 404 2ms

GET /api/todos 500 7ms - 1.36kb

ReferenceError: Todo is not defined



 at app.delete.Todo.remove._id (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-tod
o-tut1-starter\server.js:41:3)
    at callbacks (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starter\no
de_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
    at param (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starter\node_m
odules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
    at pass (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starter\node_mo
dules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-sta
rter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starte
r\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starter\node_mo
dules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\n
ode-todo-tut1-starter\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\m
ethodOverride.js:48:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starter\node_mo
dules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at multipart (C:\Users\Basel\WebstormProjects\TEST\node-todo-tut1-starter\no
de_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:27)
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});

// delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you send correct _id from client) you have to reconstruct the _id as BSON object.
Do not know what db-driver you use, but in `mongoskin` it goes like that:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

...

var proper_id = BSON.ObjectID(req.params.todo_id)
```

---

In `mangoose` try following:

```
var todo = Todo.find({_id : req.params.todo_id});
todo.remove(callback(err, todo)); // callback is optional
```

Comment: Using mongoose! I'll try this.

Comment: it has to have support for BSON objects